# How can I get socket information, from outside of a Linux process, on its socket?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm specifically interested in listening TCP sockets, but getting all and any socket (struct sock, as defined in Kernel's include/net/sock.h) information for a socket would be nice.

For example, this ss output shows a TCP socket bound to 8080.

```
tcp    LISTEN     20     128                    *:8080                  *:*      uid:500 ino:32355 sk:ffff8801b11ca880
      rto:1000 mss:536 cwnd:10
```

I assume that sk:*** is the address of the (struct sock) structure for this socket. I didn't find any tools that can grab the sk structure out and print its fields. Can I use something to get into the (is it kernel or process?) memory, and interpret data at ffff8801b11ca880 as (struct sock)?

Comment: Have you considered using the `-p` option for netstat? (e.g. `netstat -lnap`) That will give you the name/PID of the owning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address is in kernel space, because the highest 16 bits are set (FFFF). To proceed further you need GDB and debug symbols for your running kernel. I'm using CentOS, so the following worked for me:

```
# yum install gdb
# yum install --enablerepo=base-debuginfo kernel-debuginfo
# gdb /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/`uname -r`/vmlinux /proc/kcore
```

After that you can use GDB like with a userspace process, except it's the kernel:

```
(gdb) explore (struct sock *)0xffff8801b11ca880
```

Comment: I would use `debuginfo-install` instead of `yum` -- no need to specify repo, plus it tries to find the debuginfo matching the currently installed package (doesn't always succeed though)

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a better way to do it. I didn't know about that command, but I did know about the debuginfo repos, so that was what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you need.

Most of the info contained in the struct sock (**not** the struct socket) is useful only for debugging. A dump of the TCP socket table is contained in */proc/net/tcp*, and likewise for UDP, IGMP, raw,  arp, UNIX-domain. It is a plain ascii table,
whose content is briefly summerized by the headings in line 1 of this output:

```
 more /proc/net/tcp
 sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode                                                     
 0: 00000000:228B 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 15159 1 ffff8801a1ee2300 100 0 0 10 0                     
 1: 00000000:CC4B 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 13835 1 ffff8801a1ee0700 100 0 0 10 0
```

and is slightly more extensively described in the *man proc(5)* page as follows:

> /proc/net/tcp
>
> Holds a dump of the TCP socket table. Much of the information is not of use apart from debugging. The "sl" value is the kernel hash slot for the socket, the "local_address" is the local address and port number pair. The "rem_address" is the remote address and port number pair (if connected). "St" is the internal status of the socket. The "tx_queue" and "rx_queue" are the outgoing and incoming data queue in terms of kernel memory usage. The "tr", "tm->when", and "rexmits" fields hold internal information of the kernel socket state and are only useful for debugging. The "uid" field holds the effective UID of the creator of the socket.

This information is read and more conveniently displayed by commands like *lsof -i* or *netstat -4*.

Comment: In this particular case, I was interested in stuff like `sk_ack_backlog` and `sk_max_ack_backlog`, I don't think those show up in any proc entries.